# Как оптимизировать запрос? Написать запрос без or

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть, например, следующий запрос:

```
declare 
@IINBIN nvarchar(12)='531008300343'
,@address nvarchar(200)='г.Алматы'
select 
cl.*
From 
      dbo.Deals d     
left join clients c on c.clients_id = d.clientsId
where 
     (c.IINBIN = @IINBIN or @IINBIN='')
     and (c.[address] =@address or @address='')
```

Этот запрос выполняется дольше, чем запрос со следующими условиями:

```
c.IINBIN = @IINBIN and c.[address] = @address
```

Мне надо чтобы без указания параметров выборка делалась полная. т.е. оставляю поля пустыми и делается выборка без заполнения полей параметров
Как написать запрос без `or` и как его оптимизировать?

Comment: Не совсем понял семантику запроса. У вас `select cl.* from ...` (`cl` = `c` надо полагать), т.е. выбираете вы клиентов, и предикаты у вас по таблице клиентов. Для чего вам в запросе `dbo.Deals` ?

Comment: @i-one, ну это к примеру, проблема в том что запрос работает дольше при добавлении or @IINBIN=' ' или or @address=''

Comment: а условия @IINBIN=' '  нужно чтобы при пустом значении выбирались все

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятнее всего для запросов с условиями

```
where
     (c.IINBIN = @IINBIN or @IINBIN = '')
     and (c.[address] = @address or @address = '')
```

и

```
where 
     c.IINBIN = @IINBIN and c.[address] = @address
```

строятся разные планы.

Во-первых стоит конечно же посмотреть на семантику запроса и, быть может, постараться переписать его как-то более оптимально. Если в этом направлении дальше двигаться некуда, то можно попробовать следующее.

Попробовать перестроить индексы и обновить статистики (сделать это нужно для каждой из таблиц, участвующих в запросе):

```
alter index all on [TableName] rebuild
GO
update statistics [TableName] with fullscan
GO
```

Более актуальные статистики могут помочь построению более оптимального плана, а свежепостроенные нефрагментированные индексы - более быстрому его исполнению.

Также можно попробовать добавить опцию `recompile`

```
select c.*
from
    dbo.Deals d     
    left join clients c on c.clients_id = d.clientsId
where 
     (c.IINBIN = @IINBIN or @IINBIN='')
     and (c.[address] = @address or @address = '')
option (recompile)
```

Это заставит query processor каждый раз компилировать запрос заново, учитывая актуальные значения переменных `@address` и `@IINBIN`. Перекомпиляция занимает время, поэтому не всегда таким способом можно получить выигрыш.

Наконец можно разбить запрос на два независимых с помощью `if ... else`:

```
if @IINBIN != '' and @address != ''
    select c.*
    from
        dbo.Deals d     
        left join clients c on c.clients_id = d.clientsId
    where 
         c.IINBIN = @IINBIN and c.[address] = @address
else
    select c.*
    from
        dbo.Deals d     
        left join clients c on c.clients_id = d.clientsId
    where 
         (c.IINBIN = @IINBIN or @IINBIN = '')
         and (c.[address] = @address or @address = '')
```

это своеобразный компромисс между запросом с опцией `recompile` и без неё.

Ну и, конечно же, у вас должны быть полезные для запроса индексы на таблицах. Если `IINBIN` уникален, то я бы добавил индекс

```
create unique index IX_Clients_IINBIN on Clients (IINBIN) include (address)
```

если не уникален, то

```
create index IX_Clients_1 on Clients (IINBIN, address)
```

(более селективный столбец ставим вперёд).

Для случая, когда поиск идёт только по `address`, тоже можно добавить свой индекс:

```
create index IX_Clients_2 on Clients (address)
```

Вообще запросы такого вида (когда столбцы могут фильтроваться в самых разных сочетаниях.) не самые лёгкие для оптимизации, в особенности, если столбцов не 2, а намного больше.

Comment: круто спасибо, индексы проставил, c recompile или через if else быстро выполняется

Comment: @Zhandos а вы можете сравнить как быстрее? Просто если recompile достаточно - то это круто. А вот если надо использовать if/else - то для большого числа параметров придется прибегать к динамическим запросам, ведь число вариантов комбинаций фильтра растет экспоненциально...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov , сравнил, recompile достаточно и выполняется  намного быстрее

Comment: @Zhandos ок, спасибо

Comment: @Zhandos стоит учесть, что компиляция запроса может вызывать гораздо больше времени, чем его выполнение (для некоторых запросов - на несколько порядков больше), и применять ее стоит только в крайнем случае.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - генерировать запрос динамически в зависимости от установленных фильтров. Способа вместить в запрос опциональный фильтр и не потерять в оптимизации я не нашел.

---

Если речь идет о чистом SQL - то способа динамически сгенерировать запрос и не наплодить при этом инъекций - нет. Но можно добавить в базу управляемую сборку, в которой объявить функцию, которая уже сформирует динамический запрос к базе и вернет результат.

Но, поскольку решение с пользователя i-one `option(recompile)` работает достаточно быстро - необходимости расписывать этот вариант подробнее я не вижу.

Comment: прошу пример динам запроса в моем случаи

Comment: @Zhandos зависит от того, на каком языке вы его собрались составлять

Comment: @Zhandos php, java, c#, object pascal? VBA? Или вы делаете запрос из пакетного файла? Powershell?

Comment: для отчета в report builder sql server

Comment: Мда... самый плохой вариант, однако.